# When is a given polynomial a square of another polynomial?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

I meet a problem in which I hope to show a special polynomial is not a square of another polynomial. More precisely, let's consider the polynomial
$f(x):= 1-x+2bx^n-2bx^{n+1}-b^2x^{2n-1}+2b^2x^{2n}-b^2x^{2n+1}-2bx^{3n-1}+2bx^{3n}-x^{4n-1}+x^{4n}\in k[x],$ where $k$ is a field of characteristic $p>0$, $n>2$ is an integer, and $b\in k$ with $b\neq 0,1,-1$. Indeed, in the context I meet, the field $k$ is just the finite field with $p$ elements, $n=(p^m+1)/2$ with $m\geq 1$. I just try to rephrase the question in a clean and a more general way, but you may use the further assumption in your proof. I have checked for a lot of examples and I found it is always not a square of another polynomial. I believe it is true in general but I fail to give a proof for it. Please be free to give me any kind of suggestions on this problem. Although I know how to check if a concrete polynomial is a square, I have no ideas about how to systematically determine whether a general polynomial is a square or not? If you know any theory related to it, please don't hesitate to tell me. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: There is a form of quadratic reciprocity for polynomial rings in one variable over a finite field (especially if the char is not 2), deducible (at least as a mnemonic) from the reciprocity law for quadratic Hilbert symbols. I was too lazy to test this idea on your particular polynomials, but it's an obvious line.

Comment: Simul-posted to m.se, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871125/when-is-a-given-polynomial-a-square-of-another-polynomial – without notifying either site. Please don't do that!

Comment: If $f(x) = g(x)^2$, then both $f(x)$ and its derivative $f'(x)$ are divisible by $g(x)$, so in particular $\gcd(f(x), f'(x))$ is divisible by $g(x)$. Have you tried to compute $\gcd(f(x), f'(x))$? In particular, your assumption that $n=(p^m+1)/2$ is very helpful in that respect, since $2n=1$ in the field $k$.

Comment: I posted an answer in Math.SE. Unless I made a mistake we can check that $x=1$ is a zero of multiplicity two, $x=-1$ is not a zero at all, and the remaining zeros come in reciprocal pairs of equal multiplicity because $f(x)$ is palindromic. Not all those zeros can have even multiplicity because then the total multiplicity would be $\equiv2\pmod4$.